# Why is program skipping method?

Tags: c#, methods

I'm a beginner in C# and I'm working on this program consisting of 4 methods including Main(). The GetValues() allows user to input an array, the FindAverage() calculates the average of the array and now I want to create a third method 'Show()' that is supposed to display the results.
I got this working when I display the average inside Main() but when i do it inside Show(), nothing happens. While testing it, I made Show() display a simple text line "message" but when i run it. Seems like the program skips Show() and goes straight to Main(). Can any of you explain to me what's going on and what do i have to do so Show() displays it's contents?

Thank you guys!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace testscores
{
    class Program
    {        
        private static int GetValues()
        {

            string inValue;
            int[] score = new int[5];
            int total = 0;


            for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Value {0}: ", i + 1);
                inValue = Console.ReadLine();
                score[i] = Convert.ToInt32(inValue);

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
            {
                total += score[i];

            }
            return total;

        }



        //FIND AVERAGE
        private static double FindAverage()
        {
            double total = GetValues();
            double average = total/5.0;

            return average ;
        } 


         //Show

        static void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("message");
            return;
        }


        static void Main()
        {
             double avg = FindAverage();

             Console.WriteLine("The Average is :" + avg);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: you are not calling Show() anywhere...

Comment: You can be sure it doesn't get "skipped" if you do call it. I see no code where you're calling this method you're talking about, so the code you show is irrelevant. Please show the code that you're describing and where you think the problem is.

Comment: @Mitch maybe I don't type as fast as you?

Comment: Just as an additional hint: The code is not executed in the order you write it in the source code.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks man, it works now. Btw do you know what will I have to do to display on the screen the array, each value individually within Show() ?  Since GetValues() returns 'total' idk if it's even possible to get the array from it. Do you know what i mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs don't run all the code you type.  They execute each statement within `Main`, and each statement within each method that gets *called by* `Main`.

In your `Main` method, you call these other parts of your program:

- FindAverage

In your `FindAverage` method, you call these other parts:

- GetValues

In your `GetValues` method, you don't call any other parts of your program.

Nowhere in this chain do you specifically call `Show`, so it never gets called.  It just sits inside your .exe file, doing nothing.

This is called **dead code**.  It isn't a big deal, but it sounds like it isn't what you want.

To fix this, add this line somewhere in your code, wherever in your program's flow you'd like it to run:

```
Show();
```

Answer (score 4):

The entry-point for a standalone exe is **defined** as `Main(...)` - *that* is why `Main` is invoked. The static `Main` method (with various available signatures) is *special*.

For anything else: you need to call it, or it doesn't happen.

For info, you are allowed multiple such `Main` methods, but then you need to explicitly tell it which one (and only one) is the entry-point.

Answer (score 1):

Modify Show such that it takes a parameter (the value to display) and invoke it in Main:

```
static void Show(double average)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The average is: {0}", average);
}

static void Main()
{
    double avg = FindAverage();
    Show(avg);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works!.  I was treating Main as just another method. Like I said, I'm a beginner. So basically what main is doing in this piece of code is to initialize the method Show() and its contents?

Comment: Main is just another method.  It's only claim to fame is that it is the method execution is "contained" in.  That is, it is the first method executed and when it is done the program exits.

Comment: @Oskar: You're on the right track, but the terminology you used isn't quite right.  You initialize variables, structures, and classes.  Methods are actions you perform against a structure or class.  They aren't generally considered something that you can initialize.  Instead you'd say you "passed a value" to a method.  In this case, you told `Program` to `Show` the value `avg`.  `avg` was "initialized", but `Show` wasn't - it was just told what to show.  You could also say that `average` was initialized, because it is a variable.

Comment: @Oskar: I know I'm picking nits, so forgive me :)  I might also be exposing personal biases more than absolute truth (anyone else, feel free to chime in).  But it makes conversation easier when everyone is speaking the same language.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham No worries man, I completely understand. I'm new to this and I actually appreciate you aren't being condescending using difficult terminology without explaining it. And I'm glad you are bringing it up cuz that's the only way i will get to learn this right.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a C# program, .Net will call the `Main()` method.
It will not call any other methods.

To execute other methods, you need to call them (perhaps indirectly) from `Main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Every program starts only on the method `Main`.  You can't say the 
program will start on the method `Show` instead.  Put your `Show` method call within `Main`.

Also, what may seem new to you:

To give a value to a method, add it when you start the method.  For example:

```
static void Show(double value){

}
```

Then call:

```
Show(avg); // Gives the variable "avg" to Show
```